# what is the command to connect a database remotely from other PC

Tags: mysql

what is the command to connect a database remotely from other PC.

I am running a application in a PC1(client) and storing some content of that application on a database. There is also one another PC2(client). The both PC1(clients) & PC2 are within the same network connected via switch. Now i want to access that database from PC2. How it is possible ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network

Comment: @RakeshGodhala - that is about using an Apache web server...

Comment: they provide the access to phpmyadmin , which helps to access database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FTP *(File Transfer Protocol)* server should work for you. This will allow you to login to the computer's filesystem from a another computer as a user on the computer you are accessing. First you need to install and setup FTP on the computer you want to access *(PC1)* , so run this in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

After that has installed, it should be installed. Then run this:

```
sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Make sure the `write_enable` line is set to `YES`:

```
write_enable=YES
```

also remove any `#` at the beginning of that line.

You may also want to check this line:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
```

as if it is set to `YES`, or commented out with a `#`, it may allow access of anonymous users...

Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Then restart it with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

You can set up this on the other computer as well, so it is running on both computers, and you can access the data on both. The setup should be the same, just the Host IP address will be different.

---

Now, to access it, you will need a 'client' on the computer *(PC2)* you are trying to access it from as well. For this, gFTP works nicely. First install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install gftp
```

Start it, and fill in the IP address of the computer you trying to access in the `Host` field - you can find it by running `ifconfig | grep inet` on the computer you are accessing.

You can ignore the `Post` field, but generally this will be `21` or something like that. 
Then type your `Username` and `Pass`word of your user on the computer you are accessing in the boxes on the right, and make sure the drop down box on the right is set to `FTP`.

Then connect and it should work [image: smiley]

Comment: with the above steps i am able to access the database of that PC (PC1)..

Comment: `i want to access that database from PC2`? :-) Just setup `vsftpd` on PC2, and you should be able to access that as well.